# Ubuntu space usage of hiden data can't be displayed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

Running Ubuntu 20.4 in a VirtualBox VM, my storage is full. So, I try to find out, where I can remove data. And it looks like /home includes 2GB but includes 331MB. What's the real value and - if 331M is the real value - how can I free the other space?

From the command line:

```
user@NORAD:~$ sudo du -shc /*
...
2,0G    /home
...
2,8G    /snap
...
12G total
```

=> So, there should be 2 GB in /home, let's see, what is in there

```
user@NORAD:~$ sudo du -shc /home/*
2,0G    /home/user
2,0G    total
```

=> Indeed, 2GB of Data, all in folder "user"

```
user@NORAD:~$ sudo du -shc /home/user/*
324M    /home/user/back
...
331M    total
```

=> Suprise, it's just 331MB of data.

How is this possible, what am I missing here?

Comment: Not an answer.. but a good thing to know if you didn't already.  With Linux, you can mount partitions anywhere you want.  Create a new disk using virtualbox, mount it 'anywhere', rsync your home folder to it.  Then mount the disk as your new home folder via the fstab file.  You can do this with any folder in Linux.. not just $home.

Answer (score 0):

You forget that `*` does not match names starting with a dot, i.e. "hidden" files or directories. You could try to include them using:

```
shopt -s dotglob
du -shc /home/user/*
```

or in other shells,

```
du -shc /home/user/* /home/user/.[!.]*
```

Running `du -shc /home/user` (i.e. pointing it at the whole directory, not at its individual contents) should also report the same 2 GB.

Consider using `ncdu /home/user` or `broot -h -s /home/user` instead.